# Regular expression substituion vim

Tags: regex, vim

I would like to replace every occurence of the word `ANYTHING.json` with `test.ANYTHING`.
How can I do this with a vim regular expression?

Comment: Why do you need a regex for this? Seems like normal substitution to me. `:%s/xxx.json/test.xxx/g` should do the trick

Comment: Edited the question. 'xxx' should match any word, e.g. abc.json -> test.abc and also xyzxyzxyz.json -> test.xyzxyzxyz

Comment: have a look at capturing groups

Comment: Can you provide the characteristics of "ANYTHING"? Can it contain special characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
:%s/\(\w\+\)\.json/test.\1/g
```

- % - substitute on the whole file
- / - pattern to substitute
- \( - start capturing the matched pattern into the variable \1
- \w - matches any word character
- \+ - the previous pattern must be present one or more times
- \) - end capturing \1
- \. - litteral dot
- .json - litteral
- / - replace by
- test. - litteral
- \1 - insert what was matched inside the brackets
- /g - mutiple times on a line